# Java JSON Simple Parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing

When parsing some json like this:

```
{  "xxx_xxx" : "3424dfgdfg",  "xxx_xxx_xxx" : "239923sdksd" }
```

I do it like this:

```
    String respJSON = response.toString();

    Object obj1 = parser.parse(respJSON);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj1;

    String xxxxxx = (String) jsonObject.get("xxx_xxx");
```

which works fine and gets the value of xxx_xxx perfectly.

but if the json looks like this:

```
{  "some" : {    "something1" : "Nasdasdasd",    "something2" : "232423423517",
```

but with a json respose like that how can I get into the second nesting if you know what I mean, so for example pulling out the value of "something1" because if I do it the same as the first I can only access "some" from that response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract JSONObject or JSONArray from a JSONObject :

With your exemple :

{  "some" : {    "something1" : "Nasdasdasd",    "something2" : "232423423517"}}

You can access something1 by doing :

```
String respJSON = response.toString();

Object obj1 = parser.parse(respJSON);
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj1;

JSONObject some = (JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject("some");

String Nasdasdasd = (String) jsonObject.get("something1");
```

Comment: Looks good, sorry to be a pain though why am I getting this error?
 The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: Which package is imported for JSONObject in your class ? org.json.JSONObject ?

Comment: don't worry, figured it out. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

A JSONObject can contain other JSONObjects or Arrays.

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("some");
```

Comment: So knowing that how would I go about extracting the value of "something1" from the array of "some"?

Comment: Just like you did before.
jsonobject2 = jsonobject1.getJSONObject("some");
jsonobject2.getString("something1");